# Reflection is adding constructor when use with nested class

Tags: java

```
public class Singleton {

    private String name;

    private Singleton(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.getInstance();
    }

    private static Singleton INSTANCE;

    private static class SingletonHelper {

        private static Singleton getInstance() {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = new Singleton("Singleton");
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote above Singleton implementation and then reflection code to create instance, below is reflection call I tried to debug.

```
Constructor<?> constructor = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
```

When I debugged above line, I observed that reflection has kept one original constructor and created one more constructor as below:

Singleton(java.lang.String, Singleton)
and throws exception saying "wrong number of arguments".

I am not able to understand why is it taking object itself as parameter while constructing same object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `throws exception saying "wrong number of arguments".` which line of code throws an exception?

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are having is that there are actually two declared constructors in your array of declared constructors.

```
        Constructor<?>[] declaredConstructors = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for(Constructor<?> cons : declaredConstructors){
        System.out.println(cons.getParameterCount());
    }
```

The above code snippet proves you have two declared constructors. 
The first at [0] has args String and Singleton so to make this work when trying to create an object you would have to do the following.

```
    Singleton newInstance = (Singleton)constructor.newInstance("name", Singleton.getInstance());
```

The second constructor is the one you are trying to instantiate from for which you will have to have the following code

```
        Constructor<?> constructor = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[1];
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Singleton newInstance = (Singleton)constructor.newInstance("name");
```

Otherwise the linked answer tells you why there is another constructor generated hope this helps.